# pysaprk dataframe write very slow

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

We are writing spark dataframe into parquet with partition by (year, month,date) and with append mode.
The problem here is as the data is increasing in storage location(where the parquet files are stored) the time taken to write is increasing  drastically. When i checked  logs i found that filescanRDD is reading each and every parquet file available in storage location . IS there any way to improve the performance.

sample code:

```
df.repartition('day').write.partitionBy('year','month','day').parquet("location",mode='append')
```

Following is the log where there is time gap from 4:10 :15 to 5:10:15 i couldn't see anything.

```
20/01/23 04:10:15 INFO metrics: type=HISTOGRAM, name=application_1577238363313_31976.1.CodeGenerator.sourceCodeSize, count=394, min=430, max=467509, mean=4483.268903934098, stddev=5676.791863953458, median=2491.0, p75=4394.0, p95=15365.0, p98=24887.0, p99=32063.0, p999=32063.0
20/01/23 05:10:15 INFO metrics: type=GAUGE, name=application_1577238363313_31976.1.NettyBlockTransfer.shuffle-client.usedDirectMemory, value=50331648
20/01/23 05:10:15 INFO metrics: type=GAUGE, name=application_1577238363313_31976.1.NettyBlockTransfer.shuffle-client.usedHeapMemory, value=50331648
20/01/23 05:10:15 INFO metrics: type=GAUGE, name=application_1577238363313_31976.1.NettyBlockTransfer.shuffle-server.usedDirectMemory, value=50331648
20/01/23 05:10:15 INFO metrics: type=GAUGE, name=application_1577238363313_31976.1.NettyBlockTransfer.shuffle-server.usedHeapMemory, value=50331648
```

Comment: any specific reason of using coalesce ?

Comment: the size of  data we are writing is small so using coalesce

Comment: Make sure to add the following: cluster size, size of the data, spark-submit mode and full logs of the run, this way it is more easier to provide an approach. As of now the inputs are not sufficient.

Comment: i have added the logs

Answer (score 0):

You problem is related with the `mode=append`. In this mode the Spark reads all the files in the destination, in order to create new file names. You can use to change the `parquet.enable.summary-metadata` to `False`.:

```
sparkConf.set("parquet.enable.summary-metadata", "false")
```

You can export your files in another directory and them move them manually in the desired directory.

Answer (score 0):

The the problem is in your partition function. You should create in-memory partitions before disk partitions like below.

```
df=df1.repartition(col("year"),col("month"),col("day"))
df.coalesce(2).write.partitionBy('year','month','day').parquet("location",mode='append')
```

Reference: https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/partitionby/

Comment: this won't help if the dataframe has 1 large row.